# Any ROS2 interface for using MobileRobots' (now GenerationRobots) ARIA?

Tags: ros2, aria

Is there a ROS2 project that enables communication with Pioneer robot controllers using the ARIA interface?

For ROS1 I believe [ROSARIA](https://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA) was widely used but had it's problems. Has any similar ROS2 project emerged ever since? I am finding myself not beliving the contrary due to Pioneer robots' popularity.